# I need function to be executed according to status, hidden from the caller

Tags: c#, recursion, hidden

I have a C# function that look like this:

```
bool func(string name, bool retry)
{
    string res= SomeOp(name);
    if(res=="whatever")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(retry)
            return func(res, false)
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want the retry flag to be hidden from the user calling the function.

I need the function to be executed only twice.

I don't want to make the function static, and I don't want to declare an outside variable for this simple need., and a default value is not enough.
Is there is any other elegant solution?

Comment: Try making the retry a configuration variable. Based on that you could have retry flag.

Comment: Who should decide the value of `retry`? Why don't you want to declare a field for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public bool func(string name)
{
    var retryCount = 1;

    string result = string.Empty;
    while (retryCount <=2)
    {
        result = DoSomething(name);

        if(result =="Whatever")
            return true;

        retryCount ++;
    }

    return false;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public bool func(string name)
{
    return func(name, true);
}

private bool func(string name, bool retry)
{
    string res= SomeOp(name);
    if(res=="whatever")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(retry)
            return func(res, false)
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if decision is not to retry after sometime in production ?

Answer (score 0):

Beware that there is no exit condition for retry and if the answer is not "whatever" always, then the recursion does not end and we will only end with the "namesake" of this site.

```
public bool fun(string name)
{
     bool retry = Properties.Resources.retry == "true";

      string result = Get(name);
      if (result == "whatever")
      {
           return true;
       }
       else if (retry)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Retrying");
            return fun(name);
        }
        return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of having retry as bool, I would prefer having it as integer. This controls the exit condition.

```
    private bool fun(string name, int retryCount)
    {
        string result = Get(name);
        if (result == "whatever")
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (retryCount > 0)
        {
            return fun(name, retryCount - 1);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool fun(string name)
    {
        bool retry = Properties.Resources.retry == "true";
        int retryCount = Int32.Parse(Properties.Resources.retryCount);
        return fun(name, retryCount);                       
    }
```